# Android Переключение языков внутри приложения без перезагрузки

Tags: android, dialogfragment

Из фрагмента(настроек) по нажатию на TextView вызывается DialogFragment, в котором меняю настройку(язык) приложения, как мне по закрытию DialogFragment, применить настройки без перезагрузки всего приложения? а в идеале чтобы языки меняли сразу в диалоге по выбору SingleChoice. С перезагрузкой все работает. 
Вот код DialogFragment:

```
public class LanguageDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {

    final String[] itemsLang = {"English", "Russian", "Ukraine"};
    final String[] items = {"en", "ru", "uk"};
    String lang;
    MainActivity activity = new MainActivity();

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        builder.setTitle("Выберите свой родной язык")
                .setSingleChoiceItems(itemsLang, -1, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
                        lang = items[item];

                    }
                })

                .setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        App.prefs.saveLanguage(lang);
                        App.changeLang(lang);

                        reload();

                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                    }
                });

        return builder.create();
    }

    private void reload() {
        Intent intent = getActivity().getIntent();
        getActivity().finish();
        Intent LaunchIntent = getActivity().getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(App.context.getPackageName());
        startActivity(LaunchIntent);
    }
}
```

Ниже приведу пример приложения как бы я хотел реализовать:
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.funeasylearn.english
Скриншоты из него:
[image: При выборе меняется сразу и язык]
[image: При выборе меняется сразу и язык]

Answer (score 2):

Метод такой

```
public void setLocale(String lang) {
    myLocale = new Locale(lang);
    Resources res = getResources();
    DisplayMetrics dm = res.getDisplayMetrics();
    Configuration conf = res.getConfiguration();
    conf.locale = myLocale;
    res.updateConfiguration(conf, dm);
    Intent refresh = new Intent(getActivity(), MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(refresh);
}
```

Но вам так или иначе нужно перезапустить активити на которой вы находитесь, чтобы она зацепила нужные ресурсы. `lang` - это код языка. например русский это "ru"

Comment: Посмотрите приложение ссылку на которое дал, у них както сразу идет обновление

Comment: Больше похоже на то, что это готовый перевод а не использование ресурсов в зависимости от локали.

Comment: Что вы имеете ввиду под "готовый перевод"?

Comment: То есть в программе есть логика пересоздания списка и обновления экрана, сделанная не с помощью разделения ресурсов по локалям

Comment: Тогда выходит задача сводится к тому что мне нужно понять что это за логика и как ее реализовать у себя