# Локализация проекта Android

Tags: java, android, retrofit

Полностью конкретного ответа на вопрос не нашел в инете, поэтому ищу помощи тут.

Использую ButterKnife

Есть веб вариант приложения, сейчас разрабатывается мобильная версия. 
Есть проблема поддержки приложения разных языков, в вебе перевод к каждому компоненту вытаскивается с rest запроса, который возвращает json(название компонента-перевод).

Возможно ли такое сделать на андроид или все же лучше писать свой статический перевод в strings.xml? Для реализации первого варианта рассматриваю статический Map в котором будут хранится эти переводы, но проблема в реализации правильного алгоритма для перевода, как можно достать id каждого елемента без forloop'a по самому верхнему по иерархии компоненту?

Может кто-то делал свой вариант локализации приложения? Более динамическим для меня способом будет получение переводов с сервера ибо для изменения strings.xml нужно обновление целого приложения, но как это реализовать с меньшей просадкой в производительности? Спасибо

Comment: Посмотрите инструмент FireBase Remote Config. Может вам подойдет

Comment: ну так делают, файл Json имеет объект с флагом локализации, вы делаете просто запрос по локализации, если там как-то внутри то забираете всё и фильтруете по текущей локали в чем проблема то? ваш вопрос слишком общий. Нет там никаких лупов, какя просадка производительности?

Comment: @ShwarzAndrei спасибо за отклик. json имеет поле локализации en/ru и тд. и дальше ключ- значение ("название компонента": "перевод") фор лупы как раз идут по названию компонента, так как в xml файле я прописать это не смогу. Фильтровать по текущей локали можно только как я знаю данные из strings.xml ? а strings.xml во время работы приложения я заполнить не смогу, разве прописать туда все вручную. или я что-то не так понимаю

Answer (score 0):

создайте в res/ папки values-ru,values-en. и в них файл strings.xml , и в разных файлах strings пишите :res/values-ru/strings.xml`<string name="lang">ru</string>` а в res/values-en/strings.xml значение lang - en. потом в вашем активити `if(getString(R.string.lang).equals("ru")){//выполняемый код если язык русский`и так для каждого языка

Comment: спасибо за ответ. а откуда брать перевод для компонентов? в каждом активити делать такое условие и после доставать перевод для компонентов с бэкенда? мне нужно реализовать multilanguage приложение без использования strings.xml, пользуясь только данными которые возвращает rest запрос {"название компонента":"перевод"}

Comment: эти строки нужны только чтобы узнать язык. дальше нужны rest запросы для получения строк для этого языка. эхх костыли

Comment: я так понимаю лучше уже статически прописать переводы для каждого компонента в strings.xml

Comment: когда как. если хотите меньше получать данных с сервера, но есть минус приложение будет весить больше. и также наоборот

Comment: сделал статически, встретил проблему, как динамически без перегрузки приложения сменить локализацию bottom navigation drawer? (главное меню приложения) в других фрагментах и активити работает отлично, но вот меню только после ребута

Comment: [как сменить язык](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/608851/android-Переключение-языков-внутри-приложения-без-перезагрузки) + используй preference для сохранения языка и загрузки настроек в других храгментах